# Getting error while uploading file : The current request is not a multipart request in spring 4 and angular js

Tags: angularjs, spring

I am using spring 4 and angularjs, for multipart have used commons-fileupload-1.3.2.jar and commons-io-2.4.jar
I am getting error "org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: The current request is not a multipart request" while uploading the file

application-servlet.xml has entry :

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"  class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="20971520" /> 
</bean>
```

html file : `

```
<div class="padding-5 border-1">
    <input type="file" id="uploadFileName" 
           size="60" class="filestyle width100per"
           data-icon="false" file-model="importIdeaFile"
           name="filename" required>
</div>`
```

angular controller :

```
$scope.saveFile = function(){
     var filename = $scope.importIdeaFile.name;
             var formdata = new FormData();
       if(typeof $scope.importIdeaFile != 'undefined' && $scope.importIdeaFile != null && $scope.importIdeaFile !=''){
              formdata.append("file",$scope.importIdeaFile);
                     formdata.append('data',new Blob([JSON.stringify($scope.uploadPopupData)], {
                type: "application/json"
            }));$http.post('loginData/uploadIdeafile',formdata,{headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}})
                    .then(
                            function(response,status) {
                                alert(status);  
                            },
                            function(errResponse) {
                                alert(" Error while fetching User");
                            });        
       }
 }`
```

Spring Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadIdeafile", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public String uploadIdeafile(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile formdata,
              HttpServletRequest request) {
       String methodName = "uploadIdeafile(@RequestBody MultipartFile formdata, HttpServletRequest request)";
       String message = "true";
       return message;}
```

created directory :

```
WebApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
        var modelSetter = model.assign;
        element.bind('change', function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
                modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
            });
        });
    }
};}]);
```

Comment: What is your question or problem?

Comment: I am getting error "org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: The current request is not a multipart request"  while uploading the file

Answer (score 0):

I add"transformRequest: angular.identity" in http call and solved problem

```
$scope.saveFile = function(){
 var filename = $scope.importIdeaFile.name;
         var formdata = new FormData();
   if(typeof $scope.importIdeaFile != 'undefined' && $scope.importIdeaFile != null && $scope.importIdeaFile !=''){
          formdata.append("file",$scope.importIdeaFile);
                 formdata.append('data',new Blob([JSON.stringify($scope.uploadPopupData)], {
            type: "application/json"
        }));$http.post('loginData/uploadIdeafile',formdata,{headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}})
                .then(
                        function(response,status) {
                            alert(status);  
                        },
                        function(errResponse) {
                            alert(" Error while fetching User");
                        });        
   }
```

}`

New code :

```
$scope.saveFile = function(){
 var filename = $scope.importIdeaFile.name;
         var formdata = new FormData();
   if(typeof $scope.importIdeaFile != 'undefined' && $scope.importIdeaFile != null && $scope.importIdeaFile !=''){
          formdata.append("file",$scope.importIdeaFile);
                 formdata.append('data',new Blob([JSON.stringify($scope.uploadPopupData)], {
            type: "application/json"
        }));$http.post('loginData/uploadIdeafile',formdata,{
             transformRequest: angular.identity,
             headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}})
                .then(
                        function(response,status) {
                            alert(status);  
                        },
                        function(errResponse) {
                            alert(" Error while fetching User");
                        });        
   }
```

}`